# Prevent hotlinking of attachments

Tags: apache, htaccess, hotlinking

People are able to embed my forum's attachments (vbulletin).
I tried to create an htaccess rule for the hotlinking, but it did not work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule attachmentid=\d+(\&d=\d*)?|\.([Gg][Ii][Ff]|[Jj][Pp][Gg])$ http://mydomain.com/antihotlink.jpeg [R]
```

Is it not possible to check for numbers in regular expressions in htaccess files?

Comment: Please provide an example of attachment URL that you are trying to work with.

Comment: Are you sure your pattern isn't just wrong? You're not telling us what you're trying to match, so it's not really possible to answer the question.

Comment: I want to match an url like this: http://mydomain.com/forum/attachments.php?attachmentid=123456 with an optional "&d=123456" at the end...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} to match against the query string -- rewriterule matches only against the path component of the URL.

That's why your rule is a no-op.